# Can Pointer Icons be set on RecyclerView just like other Views?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have set pointer icons on all the buttons and constraint layouts that I have used but I don't know how to set pointer icons on recyclerview items. how do I implement mouse pointer icons on recyclerview items?

I tried to implement pointer icon on the inflated view but it didn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="28dp"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
    android:pointerIcon="hand"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_icon_social_apps"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:pointerIcon="hand"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I expect the pointer icon to change when the mouse hovers over the items inside the recyclerview.